# PySpark using Regexp_extract and Col to Create Dataset

Tags: regex, pyspark, computer-science, google-colaboratory

I need help creating a dataset that shows both the first name and last name of people who live in Texas and the area code of their phone numbers (phone1). This is the coding that I tried to use and this is the dataset that I was given.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col
regexp_extract(col('first_name + last_name'), '.by\s+(\w+)', 1))


first_name  last_name   company_name    address           city    county      state   zip   phone1      
Billy       Thornton    Qdoba           8142 Yougla Road  Dallas  Fort Worth  TX      34218 689-956-0765
Joe         Swanson     Beachfront      9243 Trace Street  Miami  Dade        FL      56432 890-780-9674
Kevin       Knox        MSG             7683 Brooklyn Ave  New York New York  NY      56987 850-342-1123
Bill        Lamb        AFT             6394 W Beast Dr   Houston   Galveston TX      32804 407-413-4842
Raylene     Kampa       Hermar Inc      2046 SW Nylin Rd  Elkhart   Elkhart   IN      46514 574-499-1454
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Billy Thornton  TX  689 and  Bill Lamb  TX 407

Comment: is the table dataframe? or just your txt, csv file? It seems not yet the dataframe. Then how can you call `col`?

Comment: It is a dataframe.

Comment: then why not filtering it simply `df.filter("state = 'TX'")`?

Comment: I have to get the area code of their phone numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see. Your phone number status is good to split, so use `split`.

```
df.show()

+----------+---------+------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----+-----+------------+
|first_name|last_name|company_name|          address|    city|    county|state|  zip|      phone1|
+----------+---------+------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----+-----+------------+
|     Billy| Thornton|       Qdoba| 8142 Yougla Road|  Dallas|Fort Worth|   TX|34218|689-956-0765|
|       Joe|  Swanson|  Beachfront|9243 Trace Street|   Miami|      Dade|   FL|56432|890-780-9674|
|     Kevin|     Knox|         MSG|7683 Brooklyn Ave|New York|  New York|   NY|56987|850-342-1123|
|      Bill|     Lamb|         AFT|  6394 W Beast Dr| Houston| Galveston|   TX|32804|407-413-4842|
|   Raylene|    Kampa|  Hermar Inc| 2046 SW Nylin Rd| Elkhart|   Elkhart|   IN|46514|574-499-1454|
+----------+---------+------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----+-----+------------+

df.filter("state = 'TX'") \
  .withColumn('area_code', split('phone1', "-")[0].alias('area_code')) \
  .select('first_name', 'last_name', 'state', 'area_code') \
  .show()

+----------+---------+-----+---------+
|first_name|last_name|state|area_code|
+----------+---------+-----+---------+
|     Billy| Thornton|   TX|      689|
|      Bill|     Lamb|   TX|      407|
+----------+---------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: It says last_name has invalid syntax.

Comment: Oh, you are using pyspark, what about now?

Comment: It says unexpected character after line continuation character.                         df.show() 
df.filter("state='KS'") \.withColumn('area_code', split('phone1', "-")(0).alias("area_code")) \.select('first_name', 'last_name', 'state', 'area_code') \.show()

Comment: if you add any character after `\ ` then this happen.

Comment: Now it says that DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumn.